# how to hide scrollbar in gecko webbrowser control in c#

Tags: c#-3.0, geckofx

i am trying to hide scrollbar of GeckoFx WebBrowser control,in Windows forms there is method to hide scrollbar
webBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
but in GeckoFx Webbrowser there is no property like that
i am using Navigate Method
geckowebbrowser.Navigate("Url");

Answer (score 3):

This works. You can create your own ScrollBarsEnabled property if you want.

```
webBrowser1.Document.Body.Style.CssText = "overflow: hidden ! important;";
```